# При смене профиля монитора в ubuntu 14.04 изображение визуально не меняется

Tags: ubuntu, цвета, монитор

Имеется монитор ViewSonic VX2435wm, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS с крайними обновлениями. Тестировал как на отдельной видеокарте Radeon 6780, так и на встроенной в чипсет Intel HD.

На этом мониторе цвета в Ubuntu немного перенасыщены. У меня есть icc профиль монитора, который я использовал под Windows и MacOS. После подключения его через стандартный интерфейс Color в Настройках системы, изображение не меняется.

Нет никакой разницы в воспроизведении цветов и при использовании профиля моего монитора, который идёт вместе с Ubuntu 14.04, так и с тестовом профилем "D65".

Я произвёл калибровку монитора при помощи Spyder4 и программы dispcalGUI 3.0.0. Если производить калибровку с какой-либо определенной гаммой, тогда кроме tone reproduction curve в профиле строятся кривые которые, как я понял, будут непосредственно загружаться в видео карту "video card gamma table". Если посмотреть подробную информацию о профиле в том же интерфейсе Color, эти кривые будут во вкладке "VCGT". И тогда изображение, хотя бы визуально как-то меняется.

Если же производить калибровку без изменения гаммы, то профиль будет построен без этих кривых и в профиле будут присутствовать только tone reproduction curve, вкладка "TRC". Именно ими и отличаются встроенный профиль и мой профиль от тестового профиля "D65". Похоже эти кривые не применяются, так как разницы во время переключения между этими профилями вообще никакой нет.

Если же я свой профиль загружаю в программу RawTherapee4, в которой встроена работа с профилями, то я вижу "правильные" цвета без лишней насыщенности.

Как мне сделать чтобы профиль работал на всю систему, а не только внутри программ которые поддерживают работу с профилями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла установка [`compiz-cms`](https://github.com/gebner/compiz-cms), который можно установить из командной строки:

`$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gebner/compiz-cms
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install compiz-cms`

Далее нужно установить *Менеджер настроек Compiz*:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

И включить *Color Management* в установленном менеджере ([вот так](http://itmages.ru/image/view/1074342/7a3df80d))

После этого при переключении профиля в настройках, изменения видны во всей системе.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать `xcalib` из одноимённого пакета, который в дистрибутиве `ubuntu` можно установить командой `$ sudo apt-get install xcalib`.

Пример использования (из документации):

```
$ xcalib <путь к файлу с icc>
```

С помощью опций `-d` и `-s` можно указать конкретный `display` и `screen`.